# Display categories on Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, categories

I create 1 root categori and 2 sub-categories

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bs42.jpg

AND create new static block

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyVtt.jpg

The next i make file categories.phtml in

```
app/design/frontend/default/my_template/template/catalog/navigation
```

**categories.phtml**

```
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
<?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive($_category); ?>
<?php
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
if ($immagine = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):
?>
<div style="float: left; padding-right: 30px; text-align: center;">
<div class="linkimage">
<p>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>">
<img src="<?php echo $immagine ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()) ?>" width="135" height="135" />
<?php echo $_category->getName()?>
</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

NOT WORKING!

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with your configuration and may be in list page

here is very good documentation with graphical understanding to list number of categories in cms block

just go throw [this article](http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/display-subcategory-listing-with-the-category-images-in-magento/) and you can solve your problem easily

hope this will help you sure.